# In JavaScirpt, how do I filter the elements of the same field in two arrays and return a new two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, javascript-objects

This is an example：

I want to regroup arry2 according to the fields in arry1

```
var arry1 = [
  {id: 1, parentId: 0, name: "phone"},
  {id: 2, parentId: 1, name: "nick"}
];

var arry2 = [
  {id: 7, parentId: 0, name: "phone_item1"},
  {id: 8, parentId: 1, name: "phone_item2"},
  {id: 9, parentId: 0, name: "nick_item1"},
  {id: 10, parentId: 1, name: "nick_item2"}
];


let newArrys = arry1.filter((item)=>{
   return leve_two.indexOf(arry2.parentId) == -1
})
```

I want to return a two-dimensional array:

```
[[
  {id: 7, parentId: 0, name: "phone_item1"},
  {id: 9, parentId: 0, name: "nick_item1"}
],[
  {id: 8, parentId: 1, name: "phone_item2"},
  {id: 10, parentId: 1, name: "nick_item2"}
]]
```

I tried `Array.filter`  and so on.

Can you help me?

Comment: Please review [mcve]. If you tried `Array.filter()` we need to see it to fix it.

Comment: How is arry1 related to the result? The result is just a grouping of elements by parentId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter()` method along-with `Object.values()` to get the desired output:

```js
const arr1 = [
  {id: 1, parentId: 0, name: "phone", level: 0, productCount: 0},
  {id: 2, parentId: 1, name: "nick", level: 0, productCount: 0}
];

const arr2 = [
  {id: 7, parentId: 0, name: "phone_item1", level: 1, productCount: 0},
  {id: 8, parentId: 1, name: "phone_item2", level: 1, productCount: 0},
  {id: 9, parentId: 0, name: "nick_item1", level: 1, productCount: 0},
  {id: 10, parentId: 1, name: "nick_item2", level: 1, productCount: 0}
];

const filterIds = arr1.map(({ parentId }) => parentId);

const arr3 = Object.values(arr2.reduce((r, c) => {
  r[c.parentId] = r[c.parentId] || [];
  r[c.parentId].push(c);
  return r;
}, {}));

console.log(arr3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What if arr2 parentId is classified by its arr1 id?

Comment: Could you give me some more Pointers?

Answer (score 0):

It looks just like grouping `arry2` by `parentId` and `arry1` looks useless

Use some lib for this. For example Ramda way:

```js
const result = R.pipe(
  R.groupBy(R.prop("parentId")),
  R.toPairs,
  R.map(R.last)
)(arry2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but it's not what I wanted